# video playing with Two seekBars

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-videoview, seekbar, timeline

I am creating two seekbars with one seekBar object for video playback in RecyclerView item now my problem is when I can select a video (this is first video) from device storage then automatically seekBar created and seeking, again i can select other video (this is second video) from device storage then first video playback is stopped and second video is playing with two seekBars

```
public class Videos extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private static final int PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST = 2;

    Intent videoIntent;

    public int currentVideoIndex;

    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    private FrameLayout layersContainer;

    private Uri selectedVideo;

    private VideoView videoview1 , videoview2;

    private float dx,dy;

    private List<String> items ;

    public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    public int a = 1;

    public Video video;

    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1 , mediaPlayer2;

    public SeekBar seekBar;

    List<Video> videoList = new ArrayList<>();

    RecyclerView thumbnailRecyclerView;

    public Videos(MainActivity mainActivity,RecyclerView mRecyclerView, FrameLayout layersContainer, Uri selectedVideo,

                  int currentVideoIndex,SeekBar seekBar, RecyclerView thumbnailRecyclerView) {

        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;

        this.mRecyclerView = mRecyclerView;

        this.layersContainer =layersContainer;

        this.selectedVideo = selectedVideo;

        this.currentVideoIndex = currentVideoIndex;

        this.seekBar = seekBar;

        this.thumbnailRecyclerView = thumbnailRecyclerView;

    }

    public void openVideo() {

        videoIntent = new Intent();

        videoIntent.setType("video/*");

        videoIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

   mainActivity.startActivityForResult(videoIntent.createChooser(

           videoIntent,"Select Video"),PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST);

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_VIDEO_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            if (currentVideoIndex == 0 ) {

                Toast.makeText(mainActivity,"bxb53664674 =",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                selectedVideo = data.getData();

                currentVideoIndex++;

                videoview1 = new VideoView(mainActivity);

                videoview1.setOnTouchListener(this);

                //videoview1.setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.this);

                 mediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer();

                try {

                    mediaPlayer1.setDataSource(mainActivity, selectedVideo);

                    mediaPlayer1.prepare();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                // Set up the VideoView for the current video index

                videoview1.setVideoURI(selectedVideo);

                mediaPlayer1.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {

                    @Override

                    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

                        // Calculate the scaling factor to fit the video within the maximum dimensions of the FrameLayout

                        float scaleX = (float) layersContainer.getWidth() / width;

                        float scaleY = (float) layersContainer.getHeight() / height;

                        float scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

                        // Calculate the new width and height of the video

                        int newWidthvideo = (int) (width * scale);

                        int newHeightvideo = (int) (height * scale);

                        int horizontalMargin = (layersContainer.getWidth() - newWidthvideo) / 2;

                        int verticalMargin = (layersContainer.getHeight() - newHeightvideo) / 2;

                        // Update the layout parameters of the SurfaceView to match the new dimensions

                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(newWidthvideo, newHeightvideo);

                        layoutParams.setMargins(horizontalMargin, verticalMargin, horizontalMargin, verticalMargin);

                        videoview1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                    }

                });

                  layersContainer.addView(videoview1);

                items = new ArrayList<>();

                items.add("Item 1");

                 video = new Video(selectedVideo,mediaPlayer1);

                videoList.add(video);

                VideoAdapter videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(mainActivity,videoList,videoview1,mediaPlayer1,currentVideoIndex);

                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));

                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);

                videoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else if (currentVideoIndex == 1 ) {

              // Toast.makeText(this,"currentVideoIndex =",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                selectedVideo = data.getData();

                videoview2 = new VideoView(mainActivity);

                videoview2.setOnTouchListener(this);

                 mediaPlayer2 = new MediaPlayer();

                //  mediaPlayer.reset();

                try {

                    mediaPlayer2.setDataSource(mainActivity, selectedVideo);

                    mediaPlayer2.prepare();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                // Set up the VideoView for the current video index

                videoview2.setVideoURI(selectedVideo);

                mediaPlayer2.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {

                    @Override

                    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

                        // Calculate the scaling factor to fit the video within the maximum dimensions of the FrameLayout

                        float scaleX = (float) layersContainer.getWidth() / width;

                        float scaleY = (float) layersContainer.getHeight() / height;

                        float scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

                        // Calculate the new width and height of the video

                        int newWidthvideo = (int) (width * scale);

                        int newHeightvideo = (int) (height * scale);

                        int horizontalMargin = (layersContainer.getWidth() - newWidthvideo) / 2;

                        int verticalMargin = (layersContainer.getHeight() - newHeightvideo) / 2;

                        // Update the layout parameters of the SurfaceView to match the new dimensions

                        FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(newWidthvideo, newHeightvideo);

                        layoutParams.setMargins(horizontalMargin, verticalMargin, horizontalMargin, verticalMargin);

                        videoview2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                    }

                });

                // textView1.setText(String.valueOf(currentVideoIndex));

                layersContainer.addView(videoview2);

                video = new Video(mediaPlayer2,selectedVideo);

                videoList.add(video);

                VideoAdapter videoAdapter1 = new VideoAdapter(mainActivity,mediaPlayer2,videoList,videoview2,currentVideoIndex);

                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));

                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(videoAdapter1);

                videoAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

                currentVideoIndex++;

            }

}

}

public class VideoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    MainActivity mainActivity;

    List<Video> videoList;

    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1;

    public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2;

    private VideoView videoView1;

    private VideoView videoView2;

    private VideoView videoView3;

    private VideoView videoView4;

    private VideoView videoView5;

    public Uri selectedVideo;

    public int currentVideoIndex;

     Handler handler;

   //  Context context2;

    Uri videoUri;

    private List<Uri> videoUris;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    private static final int THUMBNAIL_COUNT = 50;

    RecyclerView thumbnailRecyclerView;

    public VideoAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, List<Video> videoList, VideoView videoview1, MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1, int currentVideoIndex) {

        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;

        this.videoList = videoList;

        videoView1 = videoview1;

        this.mediaPlayer1 = mediaPlayer1;

        this.currentVideoIndex = currentVideoIndex;

    }

    public VideoAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, MediaPlayer mediaPlayer2, List<Video>

            videoList, VideoView videoview2, int currentVideoIndex) {

        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;

        this.mediaPlayer2 = mediaPlayer2;

        this.videoList = videoList;

        videoView2 = videoview2;

        this.currentVideoIndex = currentVideoIndex;

    }

    @NonNull

    @Override

    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())

                .inflate(R.layout.timeline_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    @Override

    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Video video = videoList.get(position);

        //   Uri selectedVideo = video.getSelectedVideo();

         videoUri = video.getSelectedVideo();

        // Generate thumbnails and store them in the Video object

        List<Bitmap> thumbnails = generateThumbnails(videoUri, THUMBNAIL_COUNT);

        video.setThumbnails(thumbnails);

        ThumbnailAdapter thumbnailAdapter = new ThumbnailAdapter(thumbnails);

        holder.thumbnailRecyclerView.setAdapter(thumbnailAdapter);

        SeekBar seekBar = holder.seekBar;

        thumbnailRecyclerView  = holder.thumbnailRecyclerView;

        

        if ( mainActivity != null && mediaPlayer1 != null && videoView1 != null) {

           

            holder.seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer1.getDuration());

                holder.seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer1.getCurrentPosition());

                videoView1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                    @Override

                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                        mediaPlayer1 = mp;

                      //  mediaPlayer = mediaPlayer1;

                        mediaPlayer1.seekTo(video.getCurrentPosition());

                        // mediaPlayer1.start();

                        handler = new Handler();

                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                            @Override

                            public void run() {

                                if (mediaPlayer1.isPlaying()) {

                                    video.setCurrentPosition(mediaPlayer1.getCurrentPosition());

                                    holder.seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer1.getCurrentPosition());

                                    handler.postDelayed(this, 50);

                                }

                            }

                        }, 50);

                        mediaPlayer1.start();

                    }

                });

                holder.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                    @Override

                    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                        if (fromUser && mediaPlayer1 != null) {

                            mediaPlayer1.seekTo(progress);

                            video.setCurrentPosition(progress);

                            // mediaPlayer1.seekTo(progress);

                        }

                    }

                    @Override

                    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        mediaPlayer1.pause();

                    }

                    @Override

                    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                        mediaPlayer1.start();

                    }

                });

               // currentVideoIndex++;

                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(holder.itemView.getContext(),

                        LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

               // layoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);

                holder.thumbnailRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        }else if ( mainActivity != null && mediaPlayer2 != null) {

            holder.seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer2.getDuration());

            holder.seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer2.getCurrentPosition());

            videoView2.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override

                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp2) {

                    mediaPlayer2 = mp2;

                    mediaPlayer2.seekTo(video.getCurrentPosition());

                    // mediaPlayer1.start();

                    handler = new Handler();

                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override

                        public void run() {

                            if (mediaPlayer2.isPlaying()) {

                                video.setCurrentPosition(mediaPlayer2.getCurrentPosition());

                                holder.seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer2.getCurrentPosition());

                                handler.postDelayed(this, 50);

                            }

                        }

                    }, 50);

                    mediaPlayer2.start();

                }

            });

            holder.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                @Override

                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                    if (fromUser && mediaPlayer2 != null) {

                        mediaPlayer2.seekTo(progress);

                        video.setCurrentPosition(progress);

                    }

                }

                @Override

                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    mediaPlayer2.pause();

                }

                @Override

                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                    mediaPlayer2.start();

                }

            });

           // currentVideoIndex++;

            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(holder.itemView.getContext(),

                    LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

            holder.thumbnailRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        }

    }

    private List<Bitmap> generateThumbnails(Uri videoUri, int thumbnailCount) {

        List<Bitmap> thumbnails = new ArrayList<>();

        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

        retriever.setDataSource(mainActivity, videoUri);

        long duration = Long.parseLong(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION));

        long interval = duration / (thumbnailCount + 1);

        for (int i = 1; i <= thumbnailCount; i++) {

            long time = i * interval;

            Bitmap thumbnail = retriever.getFrameAtTime(time * 1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);

            thumbnails.add(thumbnail);

        }

        try {

            retriever.release();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return thumbnails;

    }

    @Override

    public int getItemCount() {

        return videoList.size();

    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public SeekBar seekBar;

        RecyclerView thumbnailRecyclerView;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {

            super(itemView);

            thumbnailRecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnailRecyclerView);

            seekBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

        }

    }


}
```

How to solve one video playing with Two seekBars i want play one video with one seekBar like kinemastar app